# se puede guardar las respuestas de un formulario en localstorage cada radio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, radiobutton

Buenas tengo la siguiente duda, hago una mini aplicación la cual suma botones radios con muchos formularios (nueve en especifico),mi pregunta se podrá guardar cada formulario en un localstorage diferente o quizás en en arreglos y así traer las respuestas de cada formulario ejemplo :

local1 = 1,5,2,3,1,4,4,5
local2 = 2,4,3,2,5,3,1,5

```
                    <br> 
                    Texto 1      
                    <br>  

                    <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price1" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   CS 
                    <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price1" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   F
                  
                    <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price1" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">  MT
                   
                    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price1" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   O
                    
                    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price1" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   CN 
                    <br>
                    Texto 2      
                    <br>  

                    <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price2" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   CS 
                    <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price2" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   F
                  
                    <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price2" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">  MT
                   
                    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price2" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   O
                    
                    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price2" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   CN 
                    <br>
                    Texto 3     
                    <br>  

                    <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price3" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   CS 
                    <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price3" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   F
                  
                    <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price3" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">  MT
                   
                    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price3" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   O
                    
                    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price3" onchange="sumando();getPriceUpdate()">   CN 
    <input id="update" type="button" name="submitform1" value="Guardar" onclick="algo()" >     


                </form></p>
                <span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
```

en JS sumo los formularios con la siguiente función getPriceUpdate() tengo uno por cada formulario para que sume los input que correspondan,  la función sumando() suma el total de los radios chequeados, mi intención es que el boton guardar , ingrese los valores chequeados  pero tengo la duda si me restablezca la pagina y se borren las otras selecciones de los formularios

```
function getPriceUpdate(){
 const idenPermitidos=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
 let suma1=0;
 idenPermitidos.map(iden=>{
   $('input[name="price'+iden+'"]').each(function(){ 
     if($(this).is(":checked")){
         suma1+=parseInt($(this).val());
         localStorage.setItem('form1',suma1);
         document.getElementById('form1').value   = suma1;
     }
     
  })
 })
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si puedes, te hace falta hacer uso de `stringify` y `parse` dos métodos de `JSON`

Ejemplo:

```
 localStorage.setItem('form1',JSON.stringify(suma1));
const fomr1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form1'));
```